# Best place to put constants

Tags: c

1. In a multi-source file C application, which is the best place to put constant values, source file itself or in its header file? Provided that constant will be used in that source file only.
2. Is it a good way to keep `static const` in header files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't expose information you don't need to. If constant is an implementation detail of single compilation unit, there is no need to pollute global namespace. You can always add it to header later if needed.
2. Depends on the nature of constant. `static` creates new constant for each compilation unit header is included in. If constant is huge, it's better to define it once in source file, and declare it with `extern` in the header.

Comment: Thanks, what would you suggest if we want to share the constants variable across multiple source units? In headers or source file itself?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar It depends on the usage. If you need to use it in constant expressions, you need to use preprocessor `#define` or `enum`. For runtime constants: use `static const` in source file for local constants, or for global constants non-static `const` in source and `extern const` of it in header. You can also use `static const` in header for small constants, if constant variable for some reason must have internal linkage. So to answer your question, for global constant *variable*, define it in source, and declare it as `extern const` in header.

Comment: I don't want to use #define based constants because they do not offer any type safety. What I want in the project is to create a separate header file (and no source file) just for storing error values as integers in terms of const int. Can you explain a bit more when you say "You can also use  in header for small constants if constant variable for some reason must have internal linkage." Why for smaller constants? And is there any difference if I use/not-use static keyword in header file constants.

Comment: @Akay For integer error constants `enum` is usually the best option.

Comment: @AKay **Linkage:** Like I said `static` forces internal linkage, and that means that symbol is local for it's compilation unit. So, if you define static variable in header and include it in 2 source files, those 2 files will have different copies of the variable. If the constant is big (large structure or array), then you might waste memory.

Comment: @AKay **Nonstatic header constant:** You should not define non-static variable in header. They have *external* linkage, and you'll get linker error for variable redefinion if header is included in 2 or more source files. Thus non-static variables must be *defined* source file, *declared* with `extern` in header file.

Comment: Thanks @user694733